# AngularJS, only runs correctly in firefox why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm using angularjs. The example I have done works perfectly in firefox, but does not work any other browser.

The error that appears in other browsers when I press add picture botton in index is:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/...../gifwallet/add_gif.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

I do not understand is what is wrong.

---

index.html

---

```
<html lang="es" ng-app="gifwalletApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css">

  <script src="javascripts/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/angular-translate.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="src/app.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script> 

  <title>GIF Wallet</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div ng-controller="TranslateController">
   <button ng-click="changeLanguage('es')" translate="BUTTON_TEXT_ES"></button>
   <button ng-click="changeLanguage('en')" translate="BUTTON_TEXT_EN"></button>
  </div>
   <header ng-controller="MenuController">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> &nbsp;
                  <span class="badge pull-right">42</span> 
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" ng-click="add()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <h3 class="text-muted">GIF Wallet</h3>
    </header>

    <div id="images" class="row" ng-controller="gifListController"> 
        <div class="col-lg-12 media" ng-repeat="gif in giflist"> 
            <a href="" class="pull-left thumbnail">
                <img class="media-object" src="{{ gif.url }}"> 
            </a>
            <div class="media-object">
                <h4 class="media-heading">{{ gif.name }}</h4>
                <p>
                    <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> {{ 'FAVORITO' | translate }}</a>
                </p>    
                <p>
                    <a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> {{ 'ELIMINAR' | translate }}</a>
                </p>
                <p>
                    Link: <a href="">{{ gif.url }}</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <p>&copy; GIFWallet 2014</p>
    </footer>
</div>
```

---

app.js

---

```
var gifwalletApp = angular.module('gifwalletApp', ['ui.bootstrap','pascalprecht.translate']); 

gifwalletApp.config(function($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    FAVORITO: 'Favorite',
    ELIMINAR: 'Delete'
  })
 .translations('es', {
   FAVORITO: 'Favorito',
   ELIMINAR: 'Eliminar'
  });
 $translateProvider.determinePreferredLanguage();
});

gifwalletApp.controller('TranslateController', function($translate, $scope) {
  $scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
    $translate.use(langKey);
  };
});

gifwalletApp.controller('gifListController', ['$rootScope','$scope','Storage','$http', 
function($rootScope,$scope,Storage,$http){
  $scope.giflist = Storage.list();
  $rootScope.$on('reloadList', function(event, data){ 
    $scope.giflist = Storage.list();
  });

}]);

gifwalletApp.controller('MenuController', ['$rootScope','$scope', 'Storage','$modal', 
 function($rootScope,$scope, Storage, $modal) {

    $scope.add = function() {   
         $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'add_gif.html',
            controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.Gif = {};
                $scope.save = function() {

                     var image = {
                        'name': $scope.Gif.name,
                        'url': $scope.Gif.url,
                        'tags': [],
                        'favorite': false
                    };
                    Storage.save(image);

                    $rootScope.$broadcast('reloadList'); 
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');

                };

                $scope.cancel = function() {
                    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
            }
        });
    };

}
]);

 gifwalletApp.service('Storage', ['$window',    function($window) {

    var images = [];

    if (!$window.localStorage) {
        alert('No tienes localStorage activado');
    } else {
        images = $window.localStorage.getItem('gifWallet');
    }

    this.save = function(image) {

        if (images == null) {
            images = [];
        }
        else {
            images = angular.fromJson(images);    
        }
        images.push(image);
        imagesString = JSON.stringify(images);
        $window.localStorage.setItem('gifWallet', imagesString);

    }

    this.get = function(key) {

    }

    this.remove = function(key) {

    }

    this.list = function() {
        return angular.fromJson($window.localStorage.getItem('gifWallet'));
    }

}]);
```

---

add_gif.html

---

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h3 class="modal-title">Agregar GIF</h3>    
  <p class="text-muted">Añade un gif favorito a tu wallet usando el nombre y la URL</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
 <form action="" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" ng-model="Gif.name" placeholder="Corgi bailarín" class="form-control"> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="url">URL</label>
        <input type="url" id="url" ng-model="Gif.url" placeholder="http://..." class="form-control">
    </div>
 </form>
</div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="cancel()">Cancelar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()">Agregar GIF</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you check the network tab to see if it failed to download any resource in other browsers ?

Comment: Just try downloading every js and css and add from your project. means <script src="javascripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">instead of using live src

Comment: I downloading every js and css and the result is the same.

Comment: Angular makes Cross domain requests. Firefox allows it, Chrome and others don't. You're welcome. To make it run on all browsers, launch a local server (Apache, for example).

Comment: finally works:
  locally with safari and firefox
with xampp in ie, opera and chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call partials in Angular, it makes a cross domain request. **Firefox allows it, Chrome and others don't.**

So, **you have to launch a local web server to make it run on all browsers** (Apache, with Xampp / Mamp, whatever).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using the src attribute with Angular Expressions.

Use [ngSrc - as described in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).

```
<img class="media-object" ng-src="{{ gif.url }}">
```

Edit:
In your modalpanel you'll need to make sure the form that is beeing submitted is valid

Moved here from comment:

The reason why it won't work without the http:// is probably because the input field for the URL is of type="url" and urls are not valid with http/https. So it actually is a different problem here. The form should be validated before adding an image. :)

Comment: I guess he is right , more on it https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

Comment: I put ngsrc and the result was that the error disappears but remains uncharged.

Comment: Are you really having the right URL in the scope? Mind making a plunker?

Comment: Actually made a plunker very quick: http://plnkr.co/edit/Hgw9bvGXIXnDGNq6THvb?p=preview .
Seems to work for me, here in Chrome.

Comment: I tried it in plunker but pictures do not load when you add a photo.

Comment: are you using the http(s):// in front of the URL? Without it won't work for me either.

Comment: The reason why it won't work without the http:// is probably because the input field for the URL is of type="url" and urls are not valid with http/https. So it actually is a different problem here. The form should be validated before adding an image. :)

Comment: my web browser chrome launches a new error when I try to add a picture:
XMLHttpRequest can not load file: C ///: /Users/......./gifwallet/add_gif.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. angular.js: 8380
Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file: C ///: /Users/......./gifwallet/add_gif.html'.
at Error (native)
file at /// C: /Users/....../gifwallet/javascripts/angular.js: 8380: 11
at sendReq (file: C ///: /Users/...../gifwallet/javascripts/angular.js: 8183: 9)
at $ http.serverRequest (file: C ///: /Users/....../gifwallet/javascripts/angular.js...

Comment: That's because you shouldn't be using an URL from your local hardrive. Use an Image from the internet. For more information see CORS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: The error does not come when saving an image. Out when you press the button that displays the picture window add (+).

Comment: ng-src is better, but it won't resolve his problem : Chrome doesn't allow cross domain request, that's all about it :)

Comment: Well yea that's what I said up there.

Answer (score 0):

Your script only runs on firefox because firefox allow cross origin requests (AJAX requests)
and chrome will not allow cross origin request because of security policies.

So in order to run your script in chrome You have to disable web security in chrome

To disable web-securities in chrome:

1. kill the chrome process
2. press "ctrl+R" to open run menu
3. type "chrome --disable-web-security" without quotes and press enter
4. then you will be able to run your script

Please let me know If you have any issues with other browsers?

Comment: The first part is good, but the solution provided is not, IMHO. I don't think disabling web security options in Chrome can be an option...

Comment: I've provided the solution on temporary basis means I've answered what he questioned. anyway he has to host the script in server if it goes to deployment then there is no need to do anything @enguerranws