# Does Node.js Resolve AngularJs's problems rendering in non-Firefox browsers?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, apache, angular-ui-router, lamp

To my horror my AngularJS page only loads in Firefox and Android-Chrome.  These are the two environments I've been testing on, and Angular breaks (literally) everything else.  I think it's an issue with routing like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864160/angularjs-only-runs-correctly-in-firefox-why) but I'm trying to figure out if there's an easier way than mutating Apache to get it to work.  Should I use Node?  Or is there an easy solution on my LAMP stack?

Thank you!

Comment: That other reference is talking about issues when loading pages in the browser with `file:///` URLs.  Is that what you are doing?

Comment: Thanks for your attention.  No, I am using a server in a virtual machine and browsing to it.

Comment: The problem is with your "frontend" code, switching your "backend" will make no difference. (Unless you have Apache specifically setup to only serve to Firefoxs)

Comment: there are tons of reasons why your javascript would break in anything but chrome and firefox, eh hem internet explorer. check the console, you may be using features of javascript that are not supported in older browsers

Comment: Update: It works in Safari 7 (without CSS animations for obvious reasons) but fails in the latest Safari.  Also broken in iOS and Blackberry.  I've tested with base HTML so it's not a pure server issue as I thought, also CSS animations appear not to be the culprit because I can render them on their own, and a Hello World AngularJS app also seems to work.  Should I close this question and reopen a new one specifically for routes under Safari, or does anyone want to suggest an (admittedly) tangential answer here?